# Why am I prompted for my password every time I access a mounted disk under 20.04?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, password, fstab

I have several SSD disks connected on my Ubuntu server, and under 19.10, they were mounted automatically under their respective directories. But under 20.04, every time I want to access one, it asks me for my password. It shows "administrator" in the file manager. Also the file system in the shortcuts in "other locations" all show like it is a network drive.

I have the following when I type the `mount` command:

```
/dev/sda1 on /vm type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
/dev/sdc1 on /data2 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
/dev/sdd1 on /data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
/dev/sdd2 on /ISO type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
```

And I have the following under /etc/fstab:

```
# /ISO was on /dev/sdd2 during installation
UUID=fb4ab474-a5a7-4226-8f91-80d9e9278fc7 /ISO            ext4    defaults,owner   0       2
# /data was on /dev/sdd1 during installation
UUID=f0492204-e674-475d-84af-72e59454af3c /data           ext4    defaults,owner   0       2
# /data2 was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=5572ea43-44dc-45d8-b5ec-942cfb4916c9 /data2          ext4    defaults,owner   0       2
# /vm was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c66fbf3d-76f6-4072-884a-eb440623ed40 /vm             ext4    defaults,owner   0       2
```

I made sure my newly created username is the owner of the whole disks and has rw rights.

Comment: `owner`? O.o are those devices actually owned by your user? That's unusual.

Comment: I was adding those at the installation time when installing a new version of Ubuntu, like for every new version. I specified the partition and the mountpoint. I also noticed that even if I change the owner from jf:jf to root:root like for any other partition from the root directory it does not change anything. I finally noticed that one of the mount points has a "t" at the end of the file flags, where it would usually have an "x" or a "-".

Comment: I switched to cinnamon for the desktop. Same problem. Howeer, I noticed that I see a little more details about the reason for asking. I see "Action: org.gtk.vfs.file-operations" and "Vendor: GVfs"